# SQL for set of all in group by

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume I have table foo

```
A     B     C
==============
1     1     1
1     2     3
1     2     4
1     3     6
2     2     6
```

I want the set of all C where I have a duplicate AB.  Something like:

```
select all(C) from foo group by a, b having count(b) > 1
```

I want the result to be

```
all(C)
===
 3
 4
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.c
  FROM foo t1
       JOIN foo t2 ON (t1.a = t2.a AND 
                       t1.b = t2.b AND 
                       t1.rowid != t2.rowid)
```

should give you what you're after.  A bit more efficient would likely be to use an analytic function

```
SELECT c
  FROM (SELECT f.*,
               count(*) over (partition by a, b) cnt
          FROM foo f)
 WHERE cnt > 1
```

Comment: Do you see anything wrong with my sql from my answer, I'm getting a little over double the results with your sql than the one I thought up?

Comment: nevermind I had an extra where clause in mine.  the sql I came up with is faster for some reason but this works and teaches me about partition, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT C
FROM
(select C, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY A, B) AS DUPLICATES
from MY_TABLE) AS RESULTS
WHERE DUPLICATES > 1
```

Comment: A != B, I want where there are duplicate rows with AB tuples

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I used

```
select f.c from foo f
join (select a, b from foo group by a, b having count(c) > 1) dupes
on dupes.a = f.a and dupes.b = f.b;
```